# Namespace for Orbeon Forms extensions to XForms

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am pretty new to Orbeon forms. I created a simple form using xforms. I also tried to use xxforms which is the orbeon forms extension to xforms. But, whenever I used xxforms I got error. Then, I found out there is a problem with xxforms namespace.

The namespace which I used is xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"

When I tried to open the orbeon.org, I got the 504 error.

Does the above namespace is proper? If not, suggest me the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The namespace URI `http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms` is correct, although the custom now is to use `xxf` as prefix.

Maybe try with an existing example, like the [Espresso Order](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/ca030b4d93f489b50bbf20138d733b5743b0f495/src/resources/apps/xforms-espresso/espresso-order.xhtml).

There is also [documentation on XML namespaces](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xml-namespaces) which you might find useful.